# how to have a relationship continuously update in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

for example, if I say
`var a = 2;
var b = a + 2;//a is 2 b is 4
a = 3;//a is 3 b is 4`
Is there any way to set that relationship in such a way that when a changes, b changes according to the relationship and the CURRENT value of a rather than being initially set and then whatever happens to a later doesn't affect b. I know you could do something with an update function that is called every time anything changes using listeners and then reset the relationship there or in some cases use objects and pointers, but is there a way you could do it that's built into the language? I'm asking because I'm trying to display html and ui elements like sliders and I want to display the updated value of the slider as an html element in a lot of different places and use it in a lot of different places. I also run into this kind of problem all the time. Right now I'm doing this with a loop that runs every frame and that's where pretty much everything happens so I just update relationships in there and it's really inconvenient and not pleasing to read. Is there something built into the language I don't know about or even just any easier ways? I'm not asking about anything specific, I mean when you define any variable in any way, can you make that definition continuously updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a property of an object to computed a derived value. Say `a` is a property of a `state` object, you can make `b` a value derived from `a` such that `b` will always be `a + 2`.

If you want to kick off some sort of UI update every time `a` changes, then could additionally make `a` a property with a setter.

```js
let state = {
  _a: 2,
  get a(){
    return this._a
  },
  set a(v){
    this._a = v
    console.log("update state")
  },
  get b(){
    return this.a + 2
  }
}

console.log(state.a, state.b)
state.a = 3
console.log(state.b)

// change b computed value
Object.defineProperty(state, 'b', {
  get: function() { return this.a + 3; },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
console.log(state.b)
```

Comment: This is a good solution to a lot of cases, but can the relationship be changed outside of the definition of the state object?

Comment: @MikeDelmonaco I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean somehow have `b` derived from `a` without using the object?

Comment: I mean change the definition of b from a+2 to something else like 3*a later on in the code after the state object is initially defined. In other words, redefining b later on.

Comment: @MikeDelmonaco Sure, you could just redefine the property. See the example.